# c doubly linked list print backwards

Tags: c, list, printing, linked-list

I am trying to make my linked list program into a doubly linked list, however, am encountering a problem when I am trying to print my list backwards.
At the moment when I try to print backwards, it just runs a never ending loop, and I can't quite figure out where the error is.
If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong it'd be very helpful.

EDIT: I believe the problem is in the displaybackwards method, but I do not know how to change it, as removing it would cause the program to crash.

These are the parts of my current code that I think the problem may be in:

```
struct  NODE
{
    union
    {
        int  nodeCounter;
        void  *dataitem;
    }item;
    struct NODE *link;
    struct NODE *backlink;
};

struct NODE *InitList()
{
    struct NODE *temp = (struct NODE*)malloc(sizeof NODE);

    temp->item.nodeCounter = 0;
    temp->link = NULL;
    temp->backlink = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void  Add2List(struct NODE *start, struct NODE *NewNode)
{
    struct NODE *current = start;

    while (current->link != NULL)
    {
        current->backlink = current; //problem should be this line
        current = current->link;
    }
    current->link = NewNode;
    NewNode->link = NULL;
    NewNode->backlink = current;

    start->item.nodeCounter++;
}

void DisplayList(struct NODE *start)
{
    struct NODE *current = start->link;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        DisplayNode((struct inventory *)current->item.dataitem);
        current = current->link;

    }
}

void DisplayBackwards(struct NODE *start)
{
    struct NODE *current = start->link;
    while(current != NULL && current->link != NULL) //goes until current == last node
    {

        current = current->link;
        current->backlink = current;
    }

    //when current == last node
    while(current != start)// && current->backlink != NULL)
    {
        DisplayNode((struct inventory*)current->item.dataitem);
        current->link = current;
        current = current->backlink;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're modifying your list in the DisplayBackwards function. That itself is a bug. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I am trying to get to the end of the list and print by calling current->backlink, I don't understand how I am modifying the list, as the only thing I am changing is 'current' which is a local node within the function

Comment: Have you considered debugging your code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about no attempt at debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void DisplayBackwards(struct NODE *start)
{
    struct NODE *current = start;  //current points to first node
    if(current==NULL)  //if empty list, return 
       return;

    //now we are sure that atleast one node exists
    while(current->link != NULL) //goes until current == last node
    {
        current = current->link; //keep on going forward till end of list
    }

    //start from last node and keep going back till you cross the first node
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        DisplayNode((struct inventory*)current->item.dataitem);
        current = current->backlink; //go one node back
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this, I am still getting an unending loop. I'm guessing there's something else wrong in my code other than this.

Comment: Then probably you are not adding the first node to the linked list properly..this function will not cause infinite loop for correctly initialized linked list

Comment: In `Add2List`, this line is unnecessary `current->backlink = current; //mayb`

Comment: my program crashes without it though, setting current->backlink = NULL, allows me to print the last 3 items backwards, but I cannot get the entire list to work.